# What is most efficient way of finding N nearest turtles?

Tags: performance, netlogo

In Netlogo (5.3.* or 6.*) I need an efficient way of one turtle to find the agentset of the N nearest (in terms of Cartesian distance).

The obvious code:
    min-n-of N turtles [distance myself]
involves NetLogo calculating the distance to all other turtles, so O(N).
if one knows enough turtles are on the local patch one can do
    min-n-of N turtles-here [distance myself]
but testing if there are enough on the patch takes time

Comment: Can you give us an idea of the number of turtles overall and N? The ratio is important for balancing calculating all distances and spatial restrictions. Also, is it just one turtle that needs to do this, or all? If all, then some intermediate calculations can be stored for other turtles to access.